# Vue.js Access v-for $index within a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue JS to create a form which allows a user to add or remove rows as needed.

Within the container I've created a custom `Dependant` component which has a title that reads **Dependant n** where N is the position in the data array + 1.

I know that I should be able to get this count within the component with the `index` variable that exists within the scope of `v-for` however I believe that I am accessing it incorrectly from within the component.

My container markup is as follows:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="dependants">
<p>Enter the birth date and residential status of all dependants below.</p>

<ae-dependant v-for="dependant in dependants" :dob="dependant.dob" :at-home="dependant.atHome"></ae-dependant>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="addDependant"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Dependant</button>
</div>
```

I know I could always pass it as a prop but I feel that I don't need to do this.

The component and ancillaries are as below.

```
// TODO: Two way filter
Vue.filter('ISODate', function (value) {
    return value.toISOString().substr(0,10);
})

var Dependant = Vue.extend({
    props: ['dob','atHome'],
    template: '<div class="form-horizontal">'
            + '<h4>Dependant {{ index + 1 }}</h4>'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label for="dependantDOB{{ index + 1 }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date of Birth</label>'
            + '<div class="col-sm-6">'
            + '<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dependantDOB{{ index + 1 }}" v-model="dob | ISODate">'
            + '</div><div class="col-sm-4"><div class="checkbox"><label>'
            + '<input type="checkbox" id="dependantRes{{ index + 1 }}" v-model="atHome"> <b>Living at Home?</b>'
            + '</label></div></div></div></div>'
})

// Register
Vue.component('ae-dependant', Dependant)

var Dependants = new Vue ({
    el: '#dependants',
    data: {
        dependants: [{dob: new Date(),atHome: true}]
    },
    methods: {
        addDependant: function () {
            return this.dependants.push({dob: new Date(), atHome: true});
        }
    }
});
```

How should I be accessing `index` within the component?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just have to pass it as a prop.

Comment: I know you can pass it as a prop but I shouldn't need to. If I copied the content of the component all to be inline with the root I can access `index` through the implicit declaration, so when encapsulated within a component I should still be able to. It's just a case of figuring out how I an supposed to access it, e.g. this.parent.index although that doesn't work.

Comment: Check out http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Components_and_v-for

Comment: Nice find, many thanks for that.

Comment: No problem! Took me a bit longer to dig it up than I thought.